# sharp ir sensor

Tags: ros, laser, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i add 8 sharp ir into my robot, how to see in my rviz, and how to add tf for ir laser. my main laser is hokuyo ust 10lx. help me please. thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286410/sharp-ir-sensor/) by [zucky](https://answers.ros.org/users/31278/zucky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Easiest way is to add the IR frame position to your URDF robot description. Assuming you are already publishing the robot state, that should add the TF for the IR sensor automatically. You'll also have to write a node to read the analog values from the IR sensor and convert to a distance, then publish that. It's probably easiest to make the IR sensor look like a laser scanner with only a single scan point. (Reason: some off-the-shelf ROS nodes will work with laser scan messages but not single distance reading messages. Sigh...)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zucky](https://answers.ros.org/users/31278/zucky/) on 2018-04-03**:
thank you very much